# Importxml( ) outputs a bad random data instead of the searched data - Is this possible to bypass?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I use the importxml function to get information about vehicles on this website:

https://www.lacentrale.fr/listing?firstHand=true&mileageMax=40&yearMax=2020

So I used the following function :

`=IMPORTxml("https://www.lacentrale.fr/listing?firstHand=true&mileageMax=40&sortBy=priceAsc&yearMax=2020";"/html/body/section/section[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/section/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]")`

But my problem is that the price in the output is not the right one.
I get this :

"10VÉHICULE LIVRABLESUZUKI CELERIO1.0 VVT AVANTAGE**10 270 €**Offre
équitable94 - ProfessionnelVoir la distanceVoir la distanceVéhicule
livrableVoir le prix de la livraisonGarantie 17 mois 201812 km"

with a price of 10270€ instead of 8490€

> Is this a must-have site protection or is there a way to get the right price?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I compared a list of names and prices srapped by importxml and listed on the website. It's different. First I thought it could be related to google server location - maybe some taxing or change of currency. But in this case it would be always the same ratio or amount added. But it's different every time.

[image]

It looks like a protection mechanism.